# vesta panel showing ip behind nat when using remote addr in php

Tags: php, apache, nginx, vesta

hello when ever i use below php code it shows my real server ip

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>
```

but tend to show the clint ip and when i run this code

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']; ?>
```

but my code i written is using remote addr and some plugins also use then code so i cant change it how can i fix this error in vesta iam using php7.0 how can i fix it so it shows and picks client ip by remote addr